# How have you dealt with the lack of constructors in VB6?

Tags: class, vb6, constructor

VB6 classes have no parameterized constructors. What solution have you chosen for this? Using factory methods seems like the obvious choice, but surprise me!

Comment: Lack of constructors is not a good way to say it IMO. VB6 *does* indeed have parameterless constructors (`Class_Initialize` method). What it doesn't have is parameterized constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually stick to factory methods, where I put the "constructors" for related classes in the same module (.BAS extension).  Sadly, this is far from optimal since you can't really limit access to the normal object creation in VB6 - you just have to make a point of only creating your objects through the factory.

What makes it worse is having to jump between the actual object and your factory method, since organization in the IDE itself is cumbersome at best.

Comment: Or what about adding the factory method to the class itself? Putting the factory methods in a module makes them application specific.

Comment: @Dabblernl - But then you'd have to make them the equivalent of Java's `public static`, right?  VB6 doesn't have static methods.

Comment: Well, no need for a static class. You would have to create an instance to access the factory method, but as you do not make use of the object's dependencies that would be acceptable IMHO

Comment: @Dabblernl - Ah, I see. That actually sounds like a better solution, I'll have to try it out.

Comment: +1. It's worth mentioning a special case. If your class is defined in another component (e.g. ActiveX DLL), you can limit access to normal object creation. Make the class PublicNotCreatable which forces the client to use your factory method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242107(VS.60).aspx

Comment: @Dabblernl But if you're going to use a non static factory function in a "dummy" instance, why not just use an `Init()` method that you'd do your normal initialisation in?

Answer (score 6):

How about using the available class initializer? This behaves like a parameterless constructor:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' do initialization here

End Sub
```

Comment: The fact that it doesn't accept any parameters makes it pretty useless as a constructor.  It really only lets you set up a few things, but not truly initialize the object's state.

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. I meant how to solve the problem that there is only a parameterless constructor: Class_Initialize

Comment: The question was changed after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 5):

I use a mix of factory functions (in parent classes) that then create an instance of the object and call a Friend `Init()` method.

Class `CObjects`:

```
Public Function Add(ByVal Param1 As String, ByVal Param2 As Long) As CObject
  Dim Obj As CObject
  Set Obj = New CObject
  Obj.Init Param1, Param2
  Set Add = Obj
End Function
```

Class `CObject`:

```
Friend Sub Init(ByVal Param1 As String, ByVal Param2 As Long)
  If Param1 = "" Then Err.Raise 123, , "Param1 not set"
  If Param2 < 0 Or Param2 > 15 Then Err.Raise 124, , "Param2 out of range"

  'Init object state here
End Sub
```

I know the `Friend` scope won't have any effect in the project, but it acts as a warning that this is for internal use only.
If these objects are exposed via COM then the `Init` method can't be called, and setting the class to `PublicNotCreatable` [stops it being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382941/how-have-you-dealt-with-the-lack-of-constructors-in-vb6#comment3520765_3382981).

Answer (score 0):

This solution is **far** from perfect, however, this is what I ended up doing for some of my legacy projects. It's somewhat memory-efficient for storage, but just looking up something definitely takes more time than otherwise required, especially for the huge structs.

Suppose you need to implement the following,

```
type user
 id as long
 name as String
 desc as String
end type
```

But notice that VB6 natively supports Strings. So Instead of using structs, have "fake-struct" functions such as

```
Public Function user_raw(ByVal id as Long, ByRef name as String, ByRef desc as String) as String
 Const RAW_DELIM as String = "|"
 user_raw = cstr(id) & RAW_DELIM & name & RAW_DELIM & desc 
End Function
```

So as a result, you will have passable-by-value (hence stackable into arrays, or multiline Strings), "fake-structs" made of strings such as

> 1|Foo|The boss of VB
>
> 2|Bar|Foo's apprentice

So the construct also counts as a crude way to perform `to_string()`. On the slightly good side, such storage is almost instantly convertible to the Markdown table syntax.

Later on, you can retrieve data from the struct by doing something like,

```
Public const RAW_DELIM as String = "|"
Public Const POS_USER_ID = 0
Public Const POS_USER_NAME = 1
Public Const POS_USER_DESC = 2
'...
public function get_raw_variable(byref user as String, byval var as integer) as String
 dim buf() as String

 buf = SPLIT(user, "|")
 Assert ubound(buf) <= var
 get_raw_variable = buf(var)
end function
```

The retrieval is sure inefficient, but is about the best you can have. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is one trick that uses simulation of static objects in other languages.

First you create a standard **Class** with **Instancing** set to **False**.
Lets say it's name is **Class1**. Save the class.
Open it in any text editor, you should see the attribute **VB_Creatable** set to **False**. While in editor set the **VB_PredeclaredId** to **True**. This attribute can be controled in VBA IDE but not in VB6.

The class attribute section will look like this

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Class1"
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
```

The class is not creatable so you can't use New to create it.

Now add a constructor and initializer methods like this

```
Public Function Create(myConstructParams As String) As Class1
    ' create the class
    Set Create = New Class1
    ' then initialize it with any params you get from the Constructor
    Create.Init(myConstructParams)
End Function

' We're using Friend to hide the initializer from public access
' It will be available within then module though so we can add some steps to protect it.
Friend Sub Init(myConstructParams As String)
    If Me Is Class1 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError,"Error","Can't run init on class."
    End If
    ' initialization code
    .....
End Sub
```

Now in in order to create the Class1 object you have to use following syntax:

```
Dim obj As Class1
Set obj = Class1.Create("Initalize my object")
```

Since the New() can't be used on Class1 we actually made a sort of **Constructor** of a VB6 Class.