# Shortening GoToSlide Command in VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm making a PowerPoint where I'm constantly using this command to jump around slides:

```
With SlideShowWindows(1)
    .View.GoToSlide (.Presentation.Slides(x).SlideIndex)
End With
```

I wanted to shorten that by writing a module that would shorten it, but since I'm a newbie and don't really know how, I really need help. This is the "SlideControl" module I've written:

```
Public Intro As String, BIOS As String, OSBegin As String, InitialSetup As String, LogIn As String, Desktop As String

Public Sub GoToSlide(Slide)

Intro = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(1).SlideIndex
BIOS = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(2).SlideIndex
OSBegin = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(5).SlideIndex
InitialSetup = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(6).SlideIndex
LogIn = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(9).SlideIndex
Desktop = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(11).SlideIndex

SlideShowWindows(1).View.GoToSlide (Slide)

End Sub
```

That is the entire module, nothing else at the end. Of course I'm new to coding, so if the code looks wrong please help me correct it. I think I should be able to go to the intro slide using this command:

```
GoToSlide (Intro)
```

Then I get this error when I call it:

```
Compile error:

Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property
```

Can anyone help me fix this? I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: If you put that `GoToSlide (Intro)` somewhere in the middle of a module, then yes, that would be the error. A statement must be inside a procedure. [Remove the parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683) btw. And if you call that from another sub and it fails with that error, then there is some other stray code you overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close.

Based on what you've shown, you just need to make sure you list this:

```
Intro = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(1).SlideIndex
BIOS = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(2).SlideIndex
OSBegin = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(5).SlideIndex
InitialSetup = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(6).SlideIndex
LogIn = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(9).SlideIndex
Desktop = SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(11).SlideIndex
```

In a procedure that runs before you need to call the values.

Alternately, since you're basically hardcoding the values, I think you could reasonably accomplish this with an enumeration. Note the enumeration has to go at the top of the module before any of the methods.

```
Public Enum slideNum
    Intro = 1
    Bios = 2
    OSBegin = 5
    InitialSetup = 6
    Login = 9
    Desktop = 11
End Enum
Public Sub GoToSlide(slide As slideNum)
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GoToSlide (slide)
End Sub
Sub example()
    GoToslide(Login)
End sub
```

Using this second method when you are coding the GoTo Slide sub into a procedure it will automatically suggest valid slidenums I.E. Intro, Bios,OSBegin, InitialSetup,Login, or Desktop.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had to change "End Type" to "End Enum", just a note.

Comment: Oopsy got my syntax mixed up. I fixed the answer. Thanks