# VBA returning error when calling a Sub with multiple parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out why VBA is returning an error `(Compile error: Expected: =)` when I call a Subroutine and supply it with multiple parameters.

```
Sub customerController(cleanStructure As Boolean, firstCol As Integer, latCol As Integer, _
                    lngCol As Integer, Optional startRow As Long, Optional endRow As Long)
                    
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

If (cleanStructure = False) Then
    'customer data type
    If (startRow = "") Then i = 1
    If (endRow = "") Then j = countRows
    For n = i To j - i + 1
        generateURL(n, firstCol)
        newReadXMLData (url)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, latCol).Value = lat
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, lngCol).Value = lng
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

The Subroutine that I'm calling requires two parameters:

```
Sub generateURL(row As Long, column As Long)
```

Comment: also dim firstCol as Long, or you will get another error

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When calling more than 1 parameter (i.e. just `generateURL(n)` works) you need to either use

- `Call generateURL(n, firstCol)` , or
- `generateURL n, firstCol`

using `Call` is the better programming technique as [it is clearer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz(v=vs.80).aspx)

As per MSDN:

> You normally use the Call statement to call a procedure that does not return a value. If the procedure returns a value, the Call statement discards it.
>   You are not required to use the Call statement when calling a procedure. However, **it improves the readability of your code**.

Comment: I think the most reliable explanation and answer to this question is what we can find in the official documentation that Microsoft provides at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432.aspx (Calling Sub and Function Procedures).

Comment: Well, you are not required to use the Call statement ...unless you are using parentheses, apparently.

Comment: It is *wrong* that with just one parameter there is no difference between using and not using the parentheses; the effect is [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683). It is *subjective* that using `Call` improves readability; in my opinion it doesn't.