# Syntax Error On VB Subroutine Call?

Tags: vba, excel

In my Visual Basic code behind an Excel spreadsheet, I have one subroutine which takes parameters. This is called from another subroutine.

Here is the subroutine declaration:

```
Sub rowPasting(ByVal oldRow As Integer, ByVal newRow As Integer, ByVal oldSheet As Worksheet, ByVal newSheet As Worksheet)
```

Here is the call:

```
rowPasting(j,k,TTWorksheet,newSheet)
```

All the variables I use as inputs for the parameters are set and valid because they were used for working parts of the program before I tried to add this new Subroutine.

Any ideas on what is causing the syntax error on the call?

Comment: can you post the error description?

Comment: [What does the call keyword do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/479891/138938)

Comment: Duplicate of [VBA returning error when calling a Sub with multiple parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624279/vba-returning-error-when-calling-a-sub-with-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To call your subroutine you need to use one of the following syntax:

```
Call rowPasting(j,k,TTWorksheet,newSheet)
```

or

```
rowPasting j,k,TTWorksheet,newSheet
```

Comment: OMG! I must've lost a day rewriting the sub to fix this 'syntax error'... thanks for the fix.