# Error in Calling a function with multiple parameters in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a simple VBScript function written as:

```
Function check(a, b)
    response.Write(a)
End Function
```

Now when I call this function as

```
<%
check(1, 2)
%>
```

Here I get a error as

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL

The funny thing is if I change the function to get only a single parameter, it works fine. The only problem is when I put in multiple parameters in the function. This seems so simple yet I can't figure out why this error is occurring.

Comment: [Related](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. It seems when I want to call a function with multiple parameters I got do it as follow:

```
Call check(a,b)
```

or

```
check a,b
```

I took the reference from here.
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624279/vba-returning-error-when-calling-a-sub-with-multiple-parameters)