# What is happening in this code

Tags: vb6

I was looking for some vb6 that would allow me to populate a listbox with a directory of files when I found the following elegant piece of code.

```
List1.hwnd, &H18D, &H20, "directory*.*"
```

Most of the other examples I found were 4 or more lines of code. Can someone help me understand what is happening here? What is the

```
List1.hwnd, &H18D, &H20
```

Part doing?

There was a general declaration I left out.

```
  Private Declare Function SendMessageStr Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
```

Comment: Thats the whole code. I can use this and either hard code the "directory" part or use open dialog and populate a listbox with every file inside of the directory. I described what the code does in the first sentence.

Comment: it seems to me these are the values which are submitted to a function call ... the functionname is missing though ... are you sure this is the complete line ? maybe this line of code started 1 line earlier and continued on this line ?

Comment: please post a large part of the code : the whole function this is in, or at least a few lines before this line and 1 or 2 lines after this line

Comment: This can't be the entire code, as there is no definition of what `List1` is to be seen. The line as written won't do anything, because there is nothing functional there.

Comment: You are all correct. Apologies. Fairly new at this.  Main question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit still makes not enough sense - unless the code was

```
SendMessageStr List1.hwnd, &H18D, &H20, "directory*.*"
```

and you thought the space means it's a stand-alone bit ([it isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683)).

That code is

```
SendMessage (List1.hwnd, LB_DIR, DDL_ARCHIVE, "directory*.*")
```

- it sends a documented [Windows message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx) to a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775146.aspx) control named `List1` to fill it with files that match the mask `"directory*.*"`, including the archived ones.