# Compliing error, Object Required in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MinSelected(R As Range)

Dim min As Double, tmp As String

min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(R)
tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(min, "ddd/mm/dd/yyyy")
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell = tmp
End Sub
```

```
Sub MaxSelectedd(S As Range)

Dim max As Double, tmp As String

max = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(S)
tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(max, "ddd/mm/dd/yyyy")
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell = tmp

End Sub

Sub Main()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection

Module5.MinSelected (myRange)
MaxSelectedd (myRange)
End Sub
```

I'm fairly new to VBA and having some trouble with using Subs.

I'm trying to output min and max of the user selected range.

`MinSelected` method is in Module 5, and `Main` and `MaxSelectedd` are in Module 6.

`Object required` error occurs when I call `Module5.Minselected(myRange)`.

Please help me figure out why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB6 pass by value and pass by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262186/vb6-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference)

Comment: @GSerg I wouldn't say so, this is not about byRef/byVal but more about private/public.

Comment: @MarekStejskal It is not about ByRef/ByVal, it is about parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is either:

```
Call MinSelected(myRange)
Call MaxSelectedd(myRange)
```

or you can use :

```
MinSelected myRange
MaxSelectedd myRange
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much. Would I do the same if I was calling a function?

Comment: To assign the return value of a function to a variable, you will need to put arguments in parentheses. Something like that: result = MyFunction(argument)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put `Module5` before the sub, your sub/functions are public by default, meaning they can be called from all modules.

Also, you have a typo in you Max function, you are using a Worksheet min function again.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. But what if I have a function called MinSelected in Module 1? Then I'd have to call Module 5 if I want to use the sub under module 5?

Comment: No, you do not need to. Just try it. Only if you had a sub/function with a same name in multiple modules would the code crash (unless you set them to be private, meaning they would be accissible from their own module only).