# VBA "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected” on String Arrays

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic array of strings DMAs which I declare globally.

```
Dim DMAs() As String
```

I ReDim the array and assign values to it in the CreateArrayOf function which is of type String() that returns an array of type String()

```
DMAs = CreateArrayOf(Sites, 2, "", False) 

Public Function CreateArrayOf( _
    ByRef arrayFrom() As String, _
    Optional ByVal numOfChars As Integer = 2, _
    Optional ByVal filterChar As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal filterCharIsInteger As Boolean = False _
) As String()

Dim i As Integer, _
    j As Integer, _
    strn As Variant, _
    switch As Boolean, _
    strArray() As String

'numOfChars 2 for DMA with no filterChar
'numOfChars 3 for W with filterChar "W"
'numOfChars 3 for A with filterChar "A"
'numofChars 2 for D with filterChar "D"

ReDim strArray(LBound(arrayFrom) To LBound(arrayFrom))  'required in order to
'not throw error on first iteration

For i = LBound(arrayFrom) To UBound(arrayFrom)  'iterate through each site
switch = False

For Each strn In strArray 'iterate through the array to find whether the
'current site already exists
     If strn = Mid(arrayFrom(i), 1, numOfChars) And Not strn = "" Then
        switch = True
    End If
Next strn

If switch = False Then 'if it doesn't exist add it to the array
    ReDim Preserve strArray(1 To UBound(strArray) + 1)
    strArray(UBound(strArray) - 1) = Mid(arrayFrom(i), 1, numOfChars)
End If
Next i

CreateArrayOf = strArray 'return the new array
End Function
```

When I attempt to pass the DMAs array to another function OutputAnArray

```
Private Sub OutputAnArray(ByRef arrayToOutput() As String)

Dim i As Variant
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
For Each i In arrayToOutput
    Cells(x, 6).Value = i
    x = x + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

I get the "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected". Throughout the whole process I only mess with string arrays.

If I take the content of the OutputAnArray function and put it in the parent function where I'm calling it from, everything's fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you didn't show any code for CreateArrayOf() it is impossible to tell why it fails to return an array.

Comment: How are you calling OutputAnArray? You've declared it as a function but it returns no values.

Comment: @JohnColeman updated with code for CreateArrayOf(). I checked both the input and the output arrays and they're fine. Changed OutputAnArray to a Sub.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ByRef arrayToOutput() As String()` (with brackets after string to denote it as array)?

Comment: @LocEngineer `arrayToOutput()` <- denotes it as an array of type `As String` no parentheses after String. That only works when defining the function return... (pretty ass backwards but that's vba)

Comment: Just use Variant types, it's so much easier when passing between UDF's and procedures.

Comment: @SO I just switched. Can you take a look at the answer please, you might have an idea of why this is happening..

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses `()` when using a variant type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed all String definitions to Variants

```
Private Sub OutputAnArray(ByRef arrayToOutput() As Variant)
```

The culprit was still there, so then after a whole lot of attempts to get this to compile, I removed the () from the `arrayToOutput` parameter and it started working.

```
Private Sub OutputAnArray(ByRef arrayToOutput As Variant) 'fixed
```

What is still perplexing is the fact that in the following function definition, the () are needed for `arrayFrom`.

```
Public Function CreateArrayOf(ByRef arrayFrom() As Variant, _ ...
```

I really don't get it, if anyone has any idea of an explanation, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was having issues passing  a `arr() as string` to another routine, but once I changed string to variant it had no issues.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

```
"Arrays of any type can't be returned, but a Variant containing an array can."
```

If follows that the function "CreateArrayOf" does not return an array of strings: it returns a variant containing an array of strings.

The variant cannot be passed as a parameter to a function expecting an array of strings:

```
Private Sub OutputAnArray(ByRef arrayToOutput() As String)
```

It can only be passed to a function expecting a variant:

```
Private Sub OutputAnArray(ByRef arrayToOutput as Variant)
```

Conversely, DMA is an array of strings:

```
Dim DMAs() As String
```

DMA *can* be passed to a function expecting an array of strings:

```
Public Function CreateArrayOf(ByRef arrayFrom() As String, _ .
```

And finally, "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected" is a generic type mismatch message. When you pass an array of the wrong type, or a variant array, and get the error "array expected", it's not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with returning typed arrays from functions or passing typed arrays to functions as arguments. The following works as expected:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub asdfasf()
  Dim DMAs() As String

  DMAs = CreateAnArray()
  OutputAnArray DMAs
End Sub

Private Function CreateAnArray() As String()
  Dim arr() As String
  ReDim arr(1 To 5)

  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = i
  Next

  CreateAnArray = arr
End Function

Private Sub OutputAnArray(ByRef arrayToOutput() As String)
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(arrayToOutput) To UBound(arrayToOutput)
    Debug.Print arrayToOutput(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Now, you never show *how* you actually pass the `DMAs` array to `OutputAnArray`.

I'm willing to make an educated guess that you are doing

```vb
OutputAnArray (DMAs)
```

which will indeed result in

> Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

You cannot freely put parentheses in that manner. [They have special meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683).
If you want parentheses to be used when calling a sub, you must use `Call`:

```vb
Call OutputAnArray(DMAs)
```

And if you don't care, omit the parentheses like in the example above:

```vb
OutputAnArray DMAs
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error while passing an array (of user defined type) as an argument to a function ByRef.

In my case the problem was solved using the keyword "Call" in front of the function or the sub being called.

I don't really understand it, but to me it seems like VBA is trying to interpret the function/sub a couple of different ways in the absence of "Call" - which leads to the error message.

I personally try to avoid converting anything to a variant as long as possible.

Comment: Call in front fixed my issue !... me too coming from a C/C++ background avoid converting anything to variant   Thanks