# How do I enter a net use string into CMD using the VBA Shell command?

Tags: vba, shell, cmd

I'm simply trying to find the right syntax to pass the following command to cmd.

```
net use P: "\\s0501svm1\home\John Smith"
```

If I type the below then it doesn't work, presumably because the double quotes aren't being passed.

```vb
Shell ("cmd.exe /k net use P: \\s0501svm1\home\John Smith")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use proper double quotes? `Shell "cmd.exe /k net use P: " & Chr(34) & "\s0501svm1\home\John Smith" & Chr(34)` ? Also, it's better to first create the string for debugging and then to call `Shell` with that string. Also, don't use parentheses on things you don't call as functions.

Comment: `presumably because the double quotes aren't being passed` - they would have, but you did not provide any to begin with.

Comment: Argh! Why didn't I think of that! Thanks for the help, that works perfectly. I agree completely about the string thing, I just didn't bother for the example. Why not use parentheses in this situation, if you could clarify?

Comment: @PhilT https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683

Comment: Interesting. Now that I read that, it has got me before. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i think below code can work:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C net use P: ""\s0501svm1\home\John Smith"""
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me - same problem, I think. The above suggestion from Corion worked great though.