# How to handle object declaration in VBA (Error 91)

Tags: vba

I'm stuck in VBA and I couldn't find a good answer in the other questions related to error 91. I want to create an object and store variables and arrays inside that object. I tried an approach like I would do in js:

```
Dim block As Object
...
Set block = Nothing
block.Name = "Unbekannter Prüfblock"
block.Awf = "Unbekannter Anwendungsfall"
block.Conditions = Array()
block.Checks = Array()
```

I use the "Set block = Nothing" because I will use it multiple times in a loop.

But all I get is error 91 - Object variable not set

How can I set the object?
Do I really have to declare everything in vba?
Isn't there a "stop annoying me with declaration notices" toggle? ;-)

#### Update

Thank you all so much for the detailed answers!

As suggested I created a class for "block" and also a class for "condition" and "check". Block for example:

```
Option Explicit

Public name As String
Public awf As String
Public conditions As Collection
Public checks As Collection
```

Then I use it inside my code like this:

```
Dim bl As Block
Dim co As Condition
Dim ce As Check

Set bl = New Block
bl.name = ws.Range("B" & i).value
bl.awf = ws.Range("B" & i).value

Set co = New Condition
co.attr = ws.Range("B" & i).value
co.value = ws.Range("C" & i).value
bl.conditions.Add co
```

Comment: You can't call `.Name`  or `.Case` on `Nothing`. Is `block` an instance of a custom class?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you mean that you want to create a `Class`??

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+class

Comment: "Do I really have to declare everything in vba?" is sort of like asking "Do I really need to wear a helmet when riding a motorcycle?"

Comment: An alternative to a class may be the [Type statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement). See [this](https://analystcave.com/vba-the-vba-type/) for a quick start.

Comment: `bl.conditions.Add  co` without the parentheses - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262186/vb6-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference/10262247#10262247

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VBA isn't Javascript; objects and their members cannot be created inline, they need a class definition.

When you make a member call against an object, you refer to it by name, and whenever that name refers to a null reference (`Nothing`) you'll get error 91.

To fix it, you need to ensure every member call is made against a valid object reference. Using the `Set` keyword you can assign such a reference, and to create a new instance of an object you can use the `New` keyword followed by the name of the class that defines the type you want a new instance of:

```
Dim Block As Object
Block.Something = 42 ' Error 91

Set Block = New SomeClass ' set reference 
Block.Something = 42 ' OK
```

Note that because the object is declared `As Object`, every member call is late-bound (resolved at run-time); if the member doesn't exist (or if there's a typo), you'll get error 438 at run-time.

You can move this error to compile-time with early binding by using a more specific data type for the declaration:

```
Dim Block As SomeClass
```

Because the members of SomeClass are known at compile-time, the IDE will now provide you with a member completion list when you type up a member call, and typos will no longer be valid at compile-time: strive to remain in the early-bound realm whenever possible! Note: `As Variant` (explicit or not) is also similarly late-bound.

So we add a new class module and call it `SomeClass` and we add a couple of public fields:

```
Option Explicit
Public Name As String
Public Case As String 
Public Condition As Variant
Public Check As Variant
```

And now you can create and consume a new instance of that class, and add instances of it to a collection to process later (note: you can't do that with a UDT/`Type`).

The VBIDE settings have an annoying option ("automatic syntax check", IIRC) that immediately pops a message box whenever there's a compilation error on the current line; uncheck it (invalid lines will appear in red, without a message box), but do have the "require variable declaration" setting checked: it will add `Option Explicit` to every module, and that will spare you from a number of easily avoidable run-time errors, moving them to compile-time.

Comment: If had known that you are still around at SO, I wouldn't have bothered to start my own answer...

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I updated the code above. Now I'm stuck when adding to the collection. Could you maybe please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @FunThomas not as much as before, but I do still lurk and post once in a while =)

Answer (score 6):

In JS, you can add *properties* (together with values) on the fly to an object. That's not possible in VBA (and most other languages).

Your declaration `Dim block As Object` is defining a variable that is supposed to point to an *Object*. But it isn't pointing to anything yet, per default it is initialized with `Nothing`, which is, literally, *nothing*, and has neither properties nor methods, it's just a placeholder to signal *"I don't point to anything yet"*. Furthermore, `Object` cannot be instantiated.

in VBA, you assign something to an object variable with `Set` (this is different to most other languages). If you want to create a new object, you use the keyword `New`.

However, before you do that, you need to know what kind of object (which class) you need. This can be an existing class, eg a Worksheet or a Range in Excel, or it can be an own defined class (by creating a new class module in your code). In any case, you need to define the properties and the methods of that class. Considering the most simple class module `Class1` (of course you should think about a more usefull name):

```
Option Explicit
Public name as String
Public case as String
```

(I will not start to talk about private members and getter and setter).

You then write

```
Dim block As Class1
Set block = New Class1
block.name = "Unbekannter Prüfblock"
```

(But `block.data = "Hello world"` will not be possible as `data` is not a member of your class.)
Big advantage of this attempt is that the compiler can show you when you for example mistyped a property name *before* you even start your code (Debug->Compile). In JS, you will get either a runtime error or a new property on the fly - hard to find nasty bugs.

If you later need a new (empty) object, just create a new object using `New`. If the old object is not referenced anywhere else, the VBA runtime will take care that the memory is freed (so no need to write `Set block = Nothing`).

In case you really don't know the properties in advance (eg when you read XML or JSON files or a key-value list from an Excel sheet...), you can consider to use a `Collection` or a `Dictionary`. Plenty of examples on SO and elsewhere.

One remark to `block.Condition = Array()`. Arrays in VBA are not really dynamic, you cannot add or remove entries easily during runtime. In VBA, you have static and dynamic arrays:

```
Dim a(1 to 10) as String   ' Static array with 10 members (at compile time)
Dim b() as String          ' Dynamic array.
```

However, for dynamic members you need to define how many members you need *before* you write something into it, you use the `ReDim` statement for that. Useful if you can calculate the number of members in advance:

```
Redim b(1 to maxNames)     ' Dynamic array, now with maxNames members (whatever maxNames is)
```

You can change the array size of a dynamic array with `Redim Preserve`, but that should be an exception (bad programming style, inperformant). Without `Preserve`, you will get a new array, but the former data is lost.

```
Redim Preserve b(1 to maxNames+10)  ' Now with 10 more members.
```

If you really don't know the number of members and it can change often during runtime, again a `Collection` or a `Dictionary` can be the better alternative. Note that for example a Dictionary can itself a Dictionary as value, which allows to define Tree structures.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I updated the code above. Now I'm stuck when adding to the collection. Could you maybe please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell. What exactly happens? Has your `Block`-class a property `Condtions`?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your issue adding to the collection:
You need to add this code to your class module "Block" - only then you can add objects to the collections

```vb
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set conditions = New Collection
set checks = new Collection
End Sub
```